# i need to set the image value but instead of having this single String url value link how can i change it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to create a wallpaper app everything is working fine but i want to set the wallpaper which i selected but i don't know why. i only able set a single wallpaper image using a link how can i change it.

```
i  want to change this url link into the image value which is wallpagenetimage in the below code
```

```
try {
String url = 'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3899328.jpg';
int location = WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN;
var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
print(file.path.toString());
WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(file.path, location);
 }
```

And this is where the image value which i want to set it there

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors, unnecessary_this, prefer_const_constructors

import 'dart:math';
import 'package:classico/wallpaper_pages/wallpaper_bottom_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String wallpagenetimage;
  final String title;

  MainCard(
      {
      required this.title,
      required this.wallpagenetimage,});

  static getRandom() {
    final double y = Random().nextInt(250) / 100;
    if (y < 1.2)
      // ignore: curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures
      return getRandom();
    else
      // ignore: curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures
      return y;
  }

  final double y = getRandom();  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => WallpaperBottomIconsPage(
                    wallnetimage: this.wallpagenetimage,
                  ))),
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1 / y,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.black,
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: NetworkImage(this.wallpagenetimage),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i have the image data in this wall-page-net-image i want that value in there.

i tried initializing this Main-Card Into that page but its not working.

please help me.